# Открывающие и закрывающие скобки в RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения проверять наличие закрывающей и открывающей скобки или каких-либо других парных символов? К примеру, имеется строка состоящая из 32 шестнадцатеричных чисел, которая может быть в круглых скобках, фигурных, квадратных, меньше-больше. На данный момент имею выражение:

```js
var re = new RegExp("([\(][0-9A-Fa-f]{32}[\)]|[0-9A-Fa-f]{32})");
```

Но как видно из примера, с таким подходом для каждой новой пары символов придется полностью повторять первую часть выражения. В случае использования одинаковых открывающих и закрывающих символов можно было бы написать так:

```js
var re = new RegExp("((["'`´])[0-9A-Fa-f]{32}\2|[0-9A-Fa-f]{32})");
```

, т.е. можно обратиться к запоминающей скобке по ее индексу, но с парными символами такое не пройдет. Может быть существует более лаконичное выражение, чем:

```js
var re = new RegExp("("+
    "[\(][0-9A-Fa-f]{32}[\)]|"+
    "[\{][0-9A-Fa-f]{32}[\}]|"+
    "[\[][0-9A-Fa-f]{32}[\]]|"+
    "<[0-9A-Fa-f]{32}>|"+
    "[0-9A-Fa-f]{32})"
);
```

Comment: Хмм, а без регулярок никак не обойтись? Более лаконичное выражение получилось бы если искать /.[0-9A-Fa-f]{32}./, а потом проверять крайние символы на парность

Comment: а как это выражение будет использовано? только как _test_ или из него что-то будет получаться?

Comment: Вообще, проверка на соответствие открывающих/закрывающих скобок - задача не совсем для регулярок. Думаю, @Darth предлагает оптимальный способ. Как вариант: `"([\(\[<])([0-9A-Fa-f]{32})([\)\]>])"`, и проверить 1-ю и 3-ю группы на парность уже вне регулярки.

Comment: К сожалению без регулярного выражения не обойтись. Как уже писал выше, проблема не в составлении выражения, а в поиске способа его оптимизации. API определенного приложения может принимать регулярное выражение для поиска и извлечения данных из текста. Повлиять на поведение API не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть несколько путей решить задачу, например такой будет работать в JavaScript:

```
/(?=(?:\(.*\)|\[.*\]|<.*>|\{.*\}|[0-9a-f]*)$)^[\[{(<]?[0-9a-f]{32}[\]}>)]?$/i
```

Используются позиционные проверки.

Следующий способ в JavaScript работать не будет, потому что использованы условия, которые движком не поддерживаются.

```
/^(<)?(\()?(\{)?(\[)?(?<=^.?)[0-9a-f]{32}(?(1)>|(?(2)\)|(?(3)\}|(?(4)\]|))))$/i
```

---

Если первый способ для Вас легко читаем и понимаем- используйте его. Он очень прост на самом деле и не содержит дублированных последовательностей.